# How to configure "file.list" under /platforms/android/assets to take correct path?

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, gradle, mobile

My question is regarding **Node js for mobile from JaneaSystems**. I have a web-application which i convert as cordova app. I have followed all the instructions given in the getting started tutorial

https://code.janeasystems.com/nodejs-mobile/getting-started-cordova

However, while triggering the nodejs from js/index.js in the android emulator, I am getting the error as "**Initialization failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: www\nodejs-project/main.js**"

My index.js file is as follows:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },

    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
    // 'pause', 'resume', etc.
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        startNodeProject();
    },

    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();

function channelListener(msg) {
    console.log('[cordova] received:' + msg);
}

function startupCallback(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log ('Node.js Mobile Engine Started');
        nodejs.channel.send('Hello from Cordova!');
    }
};

function startNodeProject() {
    nodejs.channel.setListener(channelListener);
    nodejs.start('main.js', startupCallback);
    // To disable the stdout/stderr redirection to the Android logcat:
    // nodejs.start('main.js', startupCallback, { redirectOutputToLogcat: false });
};
```

my main.js is as follows:

```
const cordova = require('cordova-bridge');

cordova.channel.on('message', function (msg) {
  console.log('[node] received:', msg);
  cordova.channel.send('Replying to this message: ' + msg);
});
```

When i execute the command **cordova build android** a file is created with name "file.list" under /platforms/android/assets whose contents are

```
www\nodejs-project/main.js
```

Even if i manually change the above to `www\nodejs-project\main.js` I still get FileNotFound Exception.

Can anyone please tell me what am i missing as the file main.js is present under nodejs-project ?

Please let me know in case any details are required as i tried to be as thorough as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue here is that Android expects to have front-slashes on its paths, and a script that creates lists with the paths of the nodejs-mobile project paths was introducing back-slashes when developing on Windows.

This was fixed and released in nodejs-mobile-cordova 0.3.2:

- https://github.com/janeasystems/nodejs-mobile-cordova/blob/3b7ef3dd8262fbfddc02540ba74f1d2cbd49ccab/CHANGELOG.md#version-032---may-13-2019
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodejs-mobile-cordova/v/0.3.2